# Удаление строк по срезу Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Как удалить строки из датафрейма по срезу? Работаю с ексель файлом большим. Первый столбец и первые 4 строки пустые, хочу их удалить через pandas(хотя можно на VBA или xlwings).
Интуитивно хочу сделать так:

```
del df[:3]
```

Вопрос по сути в том, как обращаться к таблице не только по названиям столбцов и индексам(ключам\уникальным значениям), а по порядковым номерам. Думал проиндексировать все от 0 до конца, и удалить просто по индексу(но я не знаю как проиндексировать от 0 до последней строки)=))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Первый столбец и первые 4 строки пустые, хочу их удалить через pandas

воспользуйтесь [df.iloc[...]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[4:, 1:]
```

еще лучше вообще не читать ненужные строки и столбцы:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=4, usecols="B:ZZZ")
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Пример использования:

```
In [50]: pd.read_excel(fn)
Out[50]:
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3
0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3         0.0         1.0         2.0         3.0
4         0.0         4.0         5.0         6.0

In [51]: pd.read_excel(fn, skiprows=4, usecols="B:ZZZ")
Out[51]:
   1  2  3
0  4  5  6
```

Comment: спасибо. loc и iloc я так понял это настройка видимости обратные друг другу?

Comment: @Argo7, `.loc[]` - работает по мекам (значениям индекса и именам столбцов), а `.iloc[]` - работает по порядковым номерам строк и столбцов (нумерация всегда начинается с нуля)

Comment: опечатка у вас, не usecols, а parse_cols. И через вторйо метод все равно прочитал как обычно, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Argo7, нет, это не опечатка - параметр называется `usecols`

Comment: на второй метод все равно ругается, про usecols тоже ругается. Он независимо от наполнения уберает строки и столцбы? Просто там есть записи и первые три строки объеденены как в одну ячейку

Comment: @Argo7, смотрите пример использования в ответе

Comment: @Argo7, можете выложить ваш excel файл на какой-нибудь свободный файлообменник?

Comment: при использование usecols выдает ошибку ':' is not in list

Comment: @Argo7, может у вас древняя версия Pandas? У меня замечательно работает на Pandas 1.0.1

Comment: таки да, старая версия, прошу прощения